# python3.5 error 'dyld library not loaded: CoreFoundation' after macOS Big Sur update

Tags: python, macos

Process:               Python [1593]
Path:                  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.5.1 (3.5.1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        zsh [1569]
Responsible:           iTerm2 [1562]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-11-21 08:15:58.865 +0800
OS Version:            macOS 11.0.1 (20B29)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     5.0.1 (18P2561)
Anonymous UUID:        E76F7C18-1C08-D433-A979-D43ED08102AF

Sleep/Wake UUID:       E8807548-2D08-4BC7-840E-21E0138FEC36

Time Awake Since Boot: 1400 seconds
Time Since Wake:       210 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
dyld: No shared cache present
Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
0x100000000 -        0x100000fff +org.python.python (3.5.1 - 3.5.1) <16087962-95EF-B9B7-A634-47CA97FED0B7> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
0x7fff624d8000 -     0x7fff62573fff  dyld (832.7.1) <2705F0D8-C104-3DE9-BEB5-B1EF6E28656D> /usr/lib/dyld

Model: MacBookPro15,2, BootROM 1554.50.3.0.0 (iBridge: 18.16.12561.0.0,0), 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Core i5, 2.4 GHz, 16 GB, SMC
Graphics: kHW_IntelIrisGraphics655Item, Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/ChannelA-DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, SK Hynix, -
Memory Module: BANK 2/ChannelB-DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, SK Hynix, -
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x7BF), wl0: Sep 11 2020 16:57:49 version 9.30.440.2.32.5.61 FWID 01-129bddb
Bluetooth: Version 8.0.1f5, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
USB Device: Apple T2 Bus
USB Device: Touch Bar Backlight
USB Device: Touch Bar Display
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Headset
USB Device: Ambient Light Sensor
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Apple T2 Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 47.4
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 47.4

Comment: That is a really old version. Have you tried python 3.8 or python 3.7?

Comment: Any other version works, but the 3.5.x version doesn't. This causes a project problem and I want to fix it

Comment: It is no longer supported. You could try `tox`, but my guess is you'll have to set-up some kind of docker image if you **must** have python 3.5 on Big Sur.

Comment: I am having the same problem, any idea how to solve this properly ?

Answer (score 5):

There shouldn't be the need to uninstall python3.5.

You can just remove it from your $PATH environment variable after you made sure you've installed the latest version via `brew install python3`.

If echo $PATH looks something the like:

```sh
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

Then just replace the entry `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin` with `/usr/bin/python3` (the output of `which python3`).
This is done via:

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/python3:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

Then it should look like this:

```sh
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/python3:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

This worked for me after having trouble executing pylint.

That was my source for this:
https://www.ianmaddaus.com/post/manage-multiple-versions-python-mac/

Comment: It also worked for me but the syntax for the export of PATH environment variable should not include a dollar sign. It worked - export PATH="..."

Comment: You're right. I corrected the export statement.

Comment: Updating the paths worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
brew uninstall python3
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
```

Answer (score 1):

It is okay to use python 3.8, as it is backward compatible. So I have just deleted the old venv and created a new venv with current python version, which solved my problem.

tip: Remember to save your requirements into a txt file.

reference:
https://realpython.com/lessons/cool-new-features-python-38-overview/

Comment: could you let me know whats the process to install python 3.8 and do this replacement with venv ?

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/ follow this to install the python 3.8

Comment: ok, what do you think of downgrading python on mac ? is that allowed and not break anything in macos big sur ?

Comment: I think regardless if you are running a virtual env you would need to re-create one.

Comment: Im running to so many problems with pip versioning and dependencies, I am not able to run the older version of django. Definitely, I am creating a new venv, its totally destroyed now. The question is what do you think of installing an older version of python such as 3.7.3 that is in Catalina, is that going to break anything in Mac OS Big Sur (for example xcode, or anything)

Answer (score -6):

This also happened to me when I was trying to run **python3** from **iTerm** (replacement of terminal). This problem was not occurring with the **MacBook's default terminal**. After I updated **iTerm**, this error was not occurring anymore. Please try to update the application on which you are trying to run **python3**(in my case it was iTerm) instead of updating the python version.

Comment: dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      python3
it also happend